# Outlook Express: Consolidate inboxes?

Tags: outlook-express

I've added 3 IMAP email accounts to my outlook express, but I only want to have one inbox, where they all get sent to. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. The work-around is to forward two accounts to the third, and have only the one IMAP account set up in OE.

Comment: Well, the 3 email accounts already do receive all the same emails (there's only one mailbox for the 3 of them, but 3 different addresses), but I want to be able to send email from any of those addresses... I still have to add them as separate accounts, and then just ignore them?

Comment: Set up one IMAP account, for the main address. All your mail will arrive in that Inbox.

Set up two POP accounts, one for each of the aliased email addresses. Tell Outlook Express not to receive mail for those accounts.

In this way, you'd be able to send mail from each of the accounts.

I don't know if there's a better solution for you or not. Best of luck!